# What is the ftp file size limit in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, ftp

Is there any limit on the size of data that we can transfer using Ftp in iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native FTP support in the SDK, so you're probably referring to Apple's [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) example code or something similar.  There are no inherent caps on file size for transmission (short of 32-bit addressing issues, which may or may not come up) using the networking APIs.

However, Apple does get on your case during review for the App Store if your application uses too much bandwidth off of the cell network.  The limit I've heard quoted on this from others is [4.5 MB of data per 5 minutes of activity](http://www.mobileorchard.com/avoiding-iphone-app-rejection-from-apple/).